# Como passar o mouse em um elemento e sumir com outro sem js

Tags: css

No meu site, tenho um bloco `div` que desliza ao passar o mouse, mas por onde ele passa há o botão curtir do Facebook que está em outra área do site. De maneira nenhuma consigo que o bloco `div` cubra ou sobreponha esse botão, então pensei em fazer ele desaparecer quando eu passar o mouse no bloco `div`.

Como se eu colocasse cada um em um bloco e fizesse:

```
#sliding_block:hover #facebook_block {
    display: none;
}
```

Se fosse possível, mas não quero usar JavaScript.

Alguma solução? Ou teria algum modo de cobrir o botão do Facebook?

Consegui fazer algo parecido com o que quero no jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sr37nard/

Comment: Se é sem JS por que a tag jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Da maneira como colocou sua estrutura de `div`, você pode usar **[seletor adjacente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)** para ocultar o elemento, exemplo:

```css
#sliding_block{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#facebook_block{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
#sliding_block:hover + #facebook_block {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliding_block">
    Passe o mouse
</div>
<div id="facebook_block">
    <img style="margin: 15px 0 0 15px" width="50px" height="50px" src="http://www.gamers4fun.nl/uploads/monthly_08_2014/post-5-0-42159100-1409472635.png"/>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Adicionei apenas `float:left` para posicioná-las lado a lado.

Comment: Lembrando que obrigatoriamente o primeiro elemento após `sliding_block` deve ser o `facebook_block` impedindo uma flexibilidade na ordem dos elementos, pois o autor da pergunta disse "está em outra área do site" se referindo ao bloco do facebook.

Comment: @natan pelo que entendi os elementos são adjacentes, por que senão como ele iria cobrir o botão como ele mesmo sugeriu, se o botão estiver em outra área do site?

Answer (score 0):

Viva!

Peso que seja isto que você pretende.

```css
#a {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
            transition: 0.5s;
    
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

#a:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

#b {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    passe o mouse
</div>
<div id="b">
    <img style="margin: 15px 0 0 15px" width="50px" height="50px" src="http://www.gamers4fun.nl/uploads/monthly_08_2014/post-5-0-42159100-1409472635.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Não consegui fazer essas soluções, se alguem quiser dar uma olhada no meu projeto, eu o hospedei aqui : http://itbinds.tk/design/ ! Podem tentar co JavaScript se quizerem ! e diminuam o tamanho da tela para poderem entender ! Obrigado a todos !